# Tutorial for using spring beans in jsp pages

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

(I am not familar with technologies related to HTML delivery, like JSP... But I know basic concepts...)

In my application I use Spring Beans and Spring Security together with Blaze DS to communicate with Flex applications over AMF protocol. Everything works just fine.

Now I have a task to deliver some services via HTTP/HTML eg. it should be some sort of servlets or JSP pages that generates HTML for users. To not reproduce all business and data access logic I want to utilize my existing Spring Beans (I love Spring.). So, basically I want to create HTML view for my Spring Beans.

My question: What would be the best way to do it? Which technologies I should use? What guru-guys will suggest?

The best tip would be a link to small tutorial that will explain how to access Spring Beans for JSP pages. I tried to goole myself but there are too much information and I am a little bit nixed up with different version - so I really have no clue what should I start with...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).  You can find an introduction [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2009/jw-04-springmvc.html).

Also the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072101/accessing-spring-mvc-di-beans-from-jsp) question discusses how to do what you want specifically (i.e. access your Spring Beans from JSP pages).