# Why is my @Autowired field null here?

Tags: spring, hibernate

This is **not** a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null). So please don't close it for "*is duplicate of*" reasons..

---

I am trying to autowire a private field in my service class using [this tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-1-xml-configuration). My problem is that `restaurantOwnerRepository` remains `null` and does not get initialized.

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mahlzeit.web.server" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="restaurantOwnerRepository" class="com.mahlzeit.web.server.dao.RestaurantOwnerRepository">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Service code:

```
@Component
public class RestaurantInformationServiceImpl  extends XsrfProtectedServiceServlet implements RestaurantInformationService {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4088840947018614411L;

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantOwnerRepository restaurantOwnerRepository;

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RestaurantInformationServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public List<RestaurantDTO> getAvailableRestaurants() {

        // restaurantOwnerRepository is 'null'
        List<Restaurant> availableRestaurants = restaurantOwnerRepository.getAvailableRestaurants(getSessionId());

        return null;
    }

    private String getSessionId() {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = getThreadLocalRequest();
        return httpRequest.getSession().getId();
    }
}
```

**RestaurantOwnerRepository.java**

```
public class RestaurantOwnerRepository implements RestauranOwnerDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public RestaurantOwnerRepository(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    // ..
}
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Because first it isn't a component so will have nothing injected. You have `@Configurable` which requires an aspect and either load or compile timeweaving both of which aren't available in your configuration. Hence it will remain null.

Comment: Also it appears to be a servlet and not a service so if you have defined it as a servlet injection will never happen if you haven't setup `@Configurable` correctly.

Comment: well you are trying to autowire a bean , in a servlet which is not managed bean , instead at start up it loads the spring environment to be mapped for the chain process. Try do this example , because it will try to load a managed bean after the context has been loaded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414373/load-spring-bean-into-a-servlet

Comment: @AntJavaDev Does that mean that I'd have to load all beans "*by hand*"? Is that something I want? That means I'd have to have a `private ApplicationContext context` in each servlet to load my beans, right?

Comment: yes like that , in order to make the servlet manageable you ll have to make it contextAware at the startup , but still you will need to inject the ServiceBeans by hand , and also , why you need to autowire a DAO service in the servlet ?  arent you using the Spring MVC?

Comment: @AntJavaDev I'm pretty new to Spring and all its features.. Until now I was just using Hibernate and GWT (Google Web Toolkit). Right now I am trying to let Spring handle the Hibernate sessions for me on the server side. Regarding the DAO service .. I'm trying to make it run like it's described in  [this tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-1-xml-configuration) - I am not sure if that's the best way.

Comment: yes the example you shared is using spring MVC and hasn't implement a custom dispatcher instead of your example where you try to perform the operations in the dispatcher , try follow this approach , it should operate properly.

Comment: @AntJavaDev Alright, thank you! Do you want to provide an answer for my question here? Or should I delete it? I was following the steps from you link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414373/load-spring-bean-into-a-servlet

Comment: @AntJavaDev Am I getting this wrong..? The tutorial is autowiring `@Autowired private UserDAO userDao;` like I am autowiring `@Autowired private RestaurantOwnerRepository restaurantOwnerRepository;`. Imho I am doing the same as the tutorial.

Comment: no you are not doing the same , if you check the bean that his autowiring the dao in the tutorial , is a spring managed bean (Controller) , in your example you are preparing 2 classes of the servlet , the one is a managed bean which will never be used and the second is the actual servlet that the server uses , which do not know any context thus the dao is null , i will provide the answer with the correct controller

Comment: @AntJavaDev Oh I think I'm getting the issue now. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714018/spring-gwt-or-spring-vs-gwt) I won't really need the Spring MVC part of Spring. Thank you!

Comment: ye still you can implement the controller in order to send the data in JSON form with restful calls from GWT to the server side and the opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample controller for your example , you should define the bean in your context.xml or if you place it in this package : com.mahlzeit.web.server it will be managed by spring automatically , cause as i see you have placed the context:component-scan

```
@Controller
public class RestaurantInformationServiceImpl  {

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantOwnerRepository restaurantOwnerRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView getRestaurants( 
    HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response) { 
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("yourPage");
            List<?> rests = restaurantOwnerRepository.getAvailableRestaurants(httpRequest.getSession().getId());
            model.addObject("restList", rests );
            return model;
        }

}
```