# Exposing Spring beans in a JSP file

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

We currently have a spring project that has all off our beans defined. I wanted to put a jsp page in place that would allow me to inspect the beans (like an mbean for jconsole) that would allow me to change sizes of lists, reset the list, see the contents or even kick start a thread.

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">    
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>      
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
        <value>classpath:database.properties</value> 
        <value>classpath:log4j.properties</value>        
        </list>
    </property>      
</bean>

<bean id="mylogger" class="com.logging.Logger" />

<!-- Expose ever bean to the JSP   --> 
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> 
    <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/> 
    <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
        <list> 
            <value>mylogger</value>
            <value>properties</value> 
        </list>
    </property>  
</bean>
```

I was hoping that having my JSP file reference the objects would work like

```
${properties.LogRoot}
```

which shows the properties value but is there a similar approach to presenting the spring beans as you would a managed bean ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [accessing Spring MVC DI beans from jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072101/accessing-spring-mvc-di-beans-from-jsp)

Comment: not exactly a duplicate - the OP has set the expose property, and still doesn't get the desired result

Comment: @Bozho, thanks. The question is how to I dynamic allow my beans to be viewed on a JSP page

Answer (score 2):

Try with `${properties['LogRoot']}`. It's the usual way for accessing map values.