# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The function test must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

Tags: java, spring, jsp, parameter-passing

I'm using the following things for my project:
Spring 3.0.1 + Apache Tiles 2.2.1 + Glassfish 2.1. What I'm trying to do is to call some method in a jsp-page and pass some parameters to it. For example, I have a bean:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "singleton")
public class TestBean {
    public void test(String param){
        System.out.println("param = " + param);
    }
}
```

and I have a jsp-page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
${testBean.test("hello")}
```

This code gives me an exception like:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The function test must be used with
> a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

If I call some method without passing parameters to it - everything is OK.

I have tried to put jboss-el.jar in my WEB-INF/lib and put required parameters in web.xml (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328)), but with no effect.

I'm restricted to the set of technologies that I have listed above, so I can't add anything or, for example, can't change the version of my app-server.

With all these conditions, is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: Where is `testBean` being assigned in your EL? The error message suggests that the EL is interpreting `test()` as a function, which expects a namespace, like using the JSTL function `fn:replace()`.

Comment: It is done by Spring automatically. As explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072101/accessing-spring-mvc-di-beans-from-jsp). If i create some getter method (for example getTest()) and call it the same way (but without parameters) (for example: ${testBean.test}) - everything works fine. So the problem, i think, is specifically with parametrized call.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> *org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The function test must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified*

This indicates that the environment doesn't support the new EL 2.2 feature of invoking bean methods with arguments. The outdated environment is trying to interpret the expression as an EL function which has the notation `namespace:functionName()` (like as JSTL functions). The exception is merely complaining that `namespace:` part cannot be found in order to identify the EL function. But it is wrong, after all.

You need to ensure that the following conditions are met in order to be able to invoke bean methods with arguments in EL:

1. The target container must support EL 2.2. All Servlet 3.0 compatible containers do, as EL 2.2 is part of Java EE 6 which in turn also covers Servlet 3.0. Examples of Servlet 3.0 containers are Tomcat 7.x, Glassfish 3.x and JBoss AS 6.x/7.x.
2. The `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file is declared conform Servlet 3.0 specification (and thus not older, such as 2.5).

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app 
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0">

       <!-- Config here. -->

   </web-app>
   ```

   Otherwise your container will run in a fallback modus matching the version matching in `web.xml` root declaration, hereby losing all the new Servlet 3.0 and EL 2.2 awesomeness.
3. The webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` does **not** contain container-specific EL implementation libraries originating from a container of an older make/version, such as `el-api.jar` and/or `el-impl.jar` originating from Tomcat 6.x or so.

Your concrete problem is caused by using a non-Servlet 3.0 compatible container: the old Glassfish 2.x.

Upgrade to [Glassfish 3.x](http://glassfish.java.net) or look for alternate ways. The JBoss EL approach works only for JSF, not for Spring nor "plain JSP".

Comment: I think the problem is _Glassfish 2.1_ (as stated by @BalusC).  I remember going through a lot of trouble to get EL 2.2 working with Glassfish 2.1 and never having any success.

Comment: Thanks for help, guys (especially BalusC). So now, in my case, decision  is to avoid parametrized calls, because my environment configuration doesn't allows me to do this. And in future i need to use JSF or upgrade\change my app-server.

Answer (score 1):

Please use tomcat 7 if you are using el 2.2 and servlet 3.0
We faced the same and got fixed with above version

Answer (score 1):

Because I have to work on Servlet 2.5, I made this hack:

JSP:

```
${testBean.test["hello"]}
```

Bean:

```
private Map test;

public Map getTest() {
    if (test == null) {
        test = new Map() {
            @Override
            public Object get(Object key) {
                System.out.println("param = " + key);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public Object remove(Object key) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void putAll(Map m) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void clear() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public Set keySet() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public Collection values() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public Set entrySet() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

        };
    }
    return test;
}
```