# How to call different methods for different Locales in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, localization, jstl, el

In a JSP page I got a bean namely `School` which has a method called `getDescription(String Locale)`. If I pass `en_US` it will return English text and for `fr_CA` it will return French text.

I have no problem using fmt tags like: `<fmt:message key="school_list.title2"/>` for static content but is there a way I can pass parameter for beans so I can use something like: `${school.description}` or `${school.description(locale)}`?

Are there any good ways to handle this using standard EL and JSTL?

Answer (score 0):

Put it into the bean. Add a method getDescription() that calls the existing method with the current Locale.

Comment: The only problem with this is the bean has to be somehow aware of the current page Locale.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `#{school.getDescription(locale)}` instead?

- See also: [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812883/401881)

Answer (score 0):

If you are [using JSP 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017348/passing-parameters-to-beans-method-from-jsp#13020121) then you can go for `${school.getDescription(locale)}` or as @Med suggested, for a [deferred syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahr.html).

If your environment doesn't offer JSP 2.2 then, if you have at least JSP 2.0 then you can wrap a method call inside a generic [function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio) that takes your bean, method name to call and list of parameters and reflectively call the method. You then do something of the likes of this: `${f:invoke(bean, 'getDescription', locale)}`.

If you are on JSP 1.2 then you can get a similar behavior to the function in JSP 2.0 but using a tag instead (functions were added in JSP 2.0).