# Checking for string length in Expression language

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2, el

I am using JSF and want to have a component that should be  rendered only when the value of a String in the associated managed bean is greater than zero. I am doing this :

```
rendered="#{tabbedToolbarBean.editor.selectedQuery.length() gt 0}"
```

Additionally the signature of getter for `selectedQuery` is  `public String getSelectedQuery(){}`. I get the following error with the latest version of weblogic server.

> Error: Function length has an invalid prefix or uses the default
>   namespace which is not defined.  Correct the prefix or in a jsp
>   document, put the function inside a tag that defines the tag library
>   namespace

What am I missing?Not getting much help after googling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This means that your environment doesn't support the new EL 2.2 feature of invoking non-getter methods with parentheses.

Your best bet is using JSTL's `fn:length()` instead.

```
<html ... xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
...
rendered="#{fn:length(tabbedToolbarBean.editor.selectedQuery) gt 0}"
```

Alternatively, just use `empty` keyword in EL. The difference is that it also checks nullness.

```
rendered="#{not empty tabbedToolbarBean.editor.selectedQuery}"
```

#### See also:

- [org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The function test must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017348/org-apache-jasper-jasperexception-the-function-test-must-be-used-with-a-prefix/13020121#13020121)

Answer (score 3):

Try the JSTL fn:length() function:

```
rendered="#{fn:length(tabbedToolbarBean.editor.selectedQuery) gt 0}"
```