# How do you expose Spring beans to a Spring MVC View?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I have a `@Controller` that has a `@RequestMapping` to map an endpoint to my jsp page. In that controller, I use a `@ModelAttribute` annotation to make a `@Bean` I have in my configuration file accessible in my jsp.

```
@Controller
public class WebPageController {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    @ModelAttribute
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return myBean;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/mypage")
    public String myPage() {
        return "myPage";
    }
}
```

In my config file, I have the `@Bean`, and an `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"my.package"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean {
        return new MyBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

This works fine and I can access `myBean` on my jsp page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    version = "${myBean.version}"
</script>
```

However, I want to move my controller into the Java Config. I can accomplish the same `@RequestMapping` using a `ViewController` in my `WebConfig`.

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry viewControllerRegistry) {
    viewControllerRegistry.addViewController("/myPage").setViewName("myPage");
}
```

Now, I need to add the `myBean` as a `@ModelAttribute` to be accessible on `myPage.jsp`. How can I do this in the Java Config?

**EDIT:** This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072101/accessing-spring-mvc-di-beans-from-jsp). That shows how you would do it with xml configuration. I would like to know how to do it in my Java `@Configuration` file.

Comment: You won't be able to add model attributes through the controller registry. Instead, configure your `InternalResourceViewResolver` to expose beans to the JSP (through request attributes, which is equivalent to what happens to model attributes).

Comment: @Boann and OP, the answer is that you need to configure the `InternalResourceViewResolver`. Whether you do it in XML or Java makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I was able to configure the `InternalResourceViewResolver` in the Java Config. You can pass the name of the beans you need access to on the jsp to the `setExposedContextBeanNames` method of the `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposedContextBeanNames("myBean");
    return resolver;
}
```